# Table 'drupal.access' doesn't exist query

Tags: php, drupal-6, wamp

I am working on Drupal 6 and I have migrated it from a remote server to localhost.  I have created the backup file for the database,  and have imported that database.  Now, when I load the home page,  for example `http://localhost/abc`,  I receive the following error:

> Warning: Table 'drupal.access' doesn't exist query: SELECT 1 FROM access WHERE type = 'host' AND LOWER('127.0.0.1') LIKE LOWER(mask) AND status = 0 LIMIT 0, 1 in C:\wamp\www\ihlet1\includes\database.mysqli.inc on line 128/

Please suggest me a solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen for a couple of reasons:

1. You have the "drupal." table prefix configured in your settings.php for the remote server, and this may not work for your localhost. Remove the prefix or change it for something that works on your local MySQL installation.
2. You maybe need to run the update.php script, the DB dump may have skipped some tables and you need to make sure they're configured correctly.

Try them and tell me if it works

Comment: thanks Clive and rafaelcr for your response actually i was working with corrupt database so i had this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply the `access` table is missing from the database. Either your backup or import hasn't worked properly and that table hasn't made it through. You can run the following MySQL command to create the (empty) table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `access`;
CREATE TABLE `access` (
  `aid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mask` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `type` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`aid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```